# Access CheckBox in DataGrid (WPF) autocomplete by Sql query

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I have an empty DataGrid in a WPF interface. This DataGrid is automatically populated with the results of an SQL query and converts the Boolean values into the CheckBox within the DataGrid.
How can I access these CheckBox from C# to capture when their status changes?

[image]

```
private static void RefreshPaths(DataGrid dataGridPaths, string connectionString) {
        string commandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Paths";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);

            try {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(commandText, connection);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                dataGridPaths.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView; // DataGrid REFILL HERE
                connection.Close();
                dataAdapter.Dispose();
                connection.Dispose();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: you don't have to write `connection.Close(); connection.Dispose();`. `using (SqlConnection connection ...)` takes care of it

Comment: don't try to access checkboxes. use dt.DefaultView instead and read values from boolean column. they are synced with checkboxes

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
I used "((DataRowCollection) dt.DefaultView.Table.Rows) [1] .ItemArray [3]" to check if the value changes, but I see that this value only changes after clicking another area of the screen. I need to see the change immediately when the CheckBox was clicked. I don't understand why I can't directly access the CheckBox.
If this CheckBox exists. Wouldn't it be easier to directly access/use its properties and events?

Comment: "Wouldn't it be easier to directly access/use its properties and events?" - no, it would a lot more difficult, and often even impossible due to DataGrid virtualization